# Hover to click on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, hover

I want to convert the hover effect of my boxes on desktop to a click on mobile. On the first click the hover area should appear and only on the second click you should be redirected.

How can I solve this or what am I doing wrong?

```
<figure class="newsflash-image">
    <img src="/images/Boote-Liegeplatz/neuboote.jpg" alt="" loading="lazy">
    <h2 class="newsflash-title">
        <a href="/boote-liegeplatz">Boote und Liegeplatz</a>
    </h2>
</figure>
```

```
.newsflash-title a { color: #ffffff; display: flex; height: 100%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; transition: .5s ease-out; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 30px; }
.newsflash-title:hover a { background: rgb(0,67,100,.7); color: #ffffff; }
```

I have tried the activ, but this does not seem to work.

```
.newsflash-title:active a { background: rgb(0,67,100,.7); color: #ffffff; }
```

Comment: i think you need js to do this

Comment: for visual changes, use css media query: `@screen only and (min-width: 40em) {}` 
for behavioural changes use JavaScript `if (window.matchMedia( "screen and (min-width:40em)" )) { }`

However, It is not good for accessibility or UX to change the onClick function of a link. 
you could use `:focus` to add visual changes though.